# Is rewarding yourself for studying haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I feel lazy to study for exams so I want to reward myself everytime after studying for eg : playing video games only after studying something. Is that haram because Im making my own rule or a law  by not playing games until I study something and I've learned man made laws are evil.

Comment: Why do you feel this way? There is nothing wrong with rewarding yourself to study or do anything. As long as you are not missing any prayers, you should be fine. I would used to tell myself, "First I will first do homework, then pray Asr then go watch YouTube." And also, I don't understand how you clarify this as a "rule" since if you don't study, you can still probably play video games.

Comment: You told you "Man Made Laws are evil" ? That is not what Islam teaches. Ofcourse divine laws takes precedence on anything man made but that does not mean that they mutually exclusive. It is not a sin to stop at the red light or to pay your taxes. Also please remember, unlike Judaism, everything is allowed in Islam unless specified otherwise from the Quran & Sunnah.

Answer (score 1):

Do you follow the laws in your town/city/state/province/country?

Those are man-made laws.

As far as I’m concerned, you aren’t going against what Allah has told us in the Quran nor are you going against what the Prophet (SAWS) has done.

There is no harm in rewarding yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to tell you something very simple. "If ain't heard, it ain't heard". If you haven't heard from your parents or in the Masjid about something, then most likely it isn't wrong.

For example, a question earlier came about if they have committed shirk just by "thinking" about jins and contacting someone who just spoke about it with his friend who didn't know, but no action was committed.

If we analyze the similarity between both questions, both yours and the earlier one, you can see how both are talking about something that me or you probably haven't heard from our Masjid Imams or haven't heard from our parents.

**Disclaimer**
I am not advising that if you haven't heard something it is halal to do. I am talking more about the moral side of things. But it is always best to research or ask someone who would know.